# Is there a way to share the file path using webrtc with other users?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webrtc

I'm trying to create a small application working in real time, the purpose of this approach, is to be able to share the path of a file, that will be loaded by a user using an input, so that this same input in another users interface changes value, and takes the file path selected by the first one.

```html
<div class="imagefilesdiv" style="">
   <input type="file" multiple="" class="imagefiles" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">
</div>
```

The input tag is linked to an onchange event, which calls a function that uses the selected file, so the purpose of this application is to be able to share the file path, so thaht the function will be called automatically in the other users interface when the value of thers inputs will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRTC supports data sharing other than media by using an RTC data channel.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createDataChannel

> The RTCDataChannel interface represents a network channel which can be
>   used for bidirectional peer-to-peer transfers of arbitrary data. Every
>   data channel is associated with an RTCPeerConnection, and each peer
>   connection can have up to a theoretical maximum of 65,534 data
>   channels (the actual limit may vary from browser to browser).
>
> To create a data channel and ask a remote peer to join you, call the
>   RTCPeerConnection's createDataChannel() method. The peer being invited
>   to exchange data receives a datachannel event (which has type
>   RTCDataChannelEvent) to let it know the data channel has been added to
>   the connection.

Here is the working example: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/basic/
Source: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/datachannel/basic

The data channel is supported by all modern browsers - Chrome, FF and Safari. Unfortunately, it's not supported by Edge (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/rtcdatachannels/?filter=f3f0000bf&search=rtc&q=data%20channels)

Comment: Thanks sir for your tip, could you give more details ?